# Regex to match value in a text field

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I have 2 text fields; AddressList which is a concatenation of address lists e.g. a@demo.com;b@demo.co.uk and I have another text field called CustomerEmailAddress which just stores a single email address e.g. a@demo.com. I want to have a regex to match the AddressList to the CustomerEmailAddress. Below is the query I am using:

$(IsRegexMatch(AddressList,  /CustomerEmailAddress/i)). The issue I am having is that the AddressList is matched against the string CustomerEmailAddress and not the value in it, so no match is found.

So basically I want to match the value in textbox CustomerEmailAddress to that of the textbox AddressList e.g. CustomerEmailAddress == a@demo.com and AddressList == paul@demo.com;a@demo.com. So in this case a match is found since textbox CustomerEmailAddress matches textbox AddressList

Is it possible to do a regex match against a value in a text field?

Hope I was clear enough.

Comment: "is it possible to do.. a value.." yes it is, but put the value you dont want so I or somebody can help you.

Comment: I'm afraid you are not quite clear: what do you expect to get from your matching?
a. Find if value of textbox is contained in the value of another textbox?
b. Find if value of textbox is matched to a regexp you enter in another textbox (not the same as a. because of special characters)?
c. Find a textbox element with value matching the value of another textbox?

Comment: So basically I want to match the value in textbox CustomerEmailAddress to that of the textbox AddressList e.g. CustomerEmailAddress == a@demo.com and AddressList == paul@demo.com;a@demo.com.  So in this case a match is found since textbox CustomerEmailAddress matches textbox AddressList

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression to match email addresses and not a simple `AddressList.toLowerCase().indexOf(CustomerEmailAddress) !== -1` or something?
The reason why I am asking: this email address: `johny.doolittle@gmail.com` matches the pattern `j.h.y.do+little@gmail.com` while that is not the behaviour you want I can imagine.

Comment: I agree with AutomatedCHaos above, email addresses can contain characters (at least dot, maybe more) that have special meaning in regular expressions. You'd have to find a way to escape them before constructing your regular expression.
If you want a case-insensitive matching, you can just transform both strings to lower case. Not a 100% solution either because of unicode, but corner cases there are much more rare.